# Meaning of linearly distributed in the sentence "Let's assume that the elements of the array are linearly distributed. "

Tags: algorithm

I was reading about interpolation search at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interpolation-search when I come across this sentence "Let's assume that the elements of the array are linearly distributed." What linearly distributed means in the sentence?

Comment: It means that it assumes that the *values* in that array follows some sort of linear growth out towards the end of the array. For instance, an array containing the values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` is like this. If you were to plot this on a graph, where `x` is just the index in the array, you would get a straight line, that's what they mean, that the values lies around such a straight line. This array is not linearly distributed: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000]`.

Comment: The reason why it assumes this is actually the reverse, the algorithm is suitable *if* your data is distributed in such a manner. The algorithm works by estimating where in the array the value should be, *given that the values are linearly distributed*. And then adjusts if it missed it slightly. However, if the data does not follow this linearly distributed concept, this estimate will be wrong most of the time, and then this algorithm isn't suitable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about terminology, not a question about programming. Please try for example https://cs.stackexchange.com or possibly https://math.stackexchange.com, or a [search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+a+linear+distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean "following an arithmetic progression" or approximately so. The idea is that smoothly varying data is predictable to some extent.

You can use this knowledge to speed-up the search by estimating where the target value could be located, from the knowledge of some values.

E.g. in the sorted sequence 14, 22, 31, 46, 55, 57, 70, 78, 91, 99, the value 31 is likely to be the 3rd element (inverse linear interpolation between 14 and 99 yields the index 2.8, which rounds to 3).

One could also say *uniformly* distributed. If the data is not so spread, interpolation search can be counter-productive.